# Get the sender from email with Mailkit v2.9.0

Tags: c#, mailkit

How I get the e-mail-address from the email-object in Mailkit v2.9.0.

I'm fetching the message, put it into a [IMessageSummary](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_IMessageSummary.htm), loop throw it and trying to use the [Envelope.From](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_Envelope_From.htm) or [Envelope.Sender](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_Envelope_From.htm) method.

The loop and fetch method:

```
IList<IMessageSummary> fetched = null;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                int startIndex = messages.Count;

                fetched = client.Inbox.Fetch(startIndex, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId, cancel.Token);
                break;
            }
            catch (ImapProtocolException)
            {
                await ReconnectAsync();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                await ReconnectAsync();
            }
        } while (true);

        foreach (var message in fetched)
        {
            try
            {
                if(!(message.Flags.Value.HasFlag(MessageFlags.Seen)))
                {

                    client.Inbox.AddFlags(message.UniqueId, MessageFlags.Seen, false);
                    if (message.TextBody != null)
                    {
                        var mime = (TextPart)client.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.TextBody);
                        text = mime.Text;

                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", message.Envelope.Subject);
                        //Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                        Console.WriteLine("a:: " + message.Envelope.From);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var mime = (TextPart)client.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.HtmlBody);
                        text = mime.Text;
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Nachricht eingegangen:");
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", message.Envelope.Subject);
                        //Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                        Console.WriteLine("b:: " + message.Envelope.Sender);
                    }
```

With

```
 message.Envelope.Sender
```

I'm getting no output.

With

```
 message.Envelope.From
```

I'm getting the following output (Maybe the mailbox-name from the exchange & the e-mail):

```
"Lastname, Firstname (Companyname)" <f.lastname@company.com>
```

Original Output:

```
S: * 22 FETCH (UID 595 FLAGS (\Seen) INTERNALDATE "29-Oct-2020 09:47:37 +0100" RFC822.SIZE 6852 ENVELOPE ("Thu, 29 Oct 2020 09:47:36 +0100" "fsfsfsf" (("Company Mailbox - Information" NIL "info" "company.net")) NIL NIL (("Company Ticketsystem" NIL "ticket" "company.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<68bc049065254f68b7f9da77602e50a1@company.net>") BODY ("text" "plain" ("charset" "iso-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 0 0))
```

I dont want to parse the output of **Envelope.From**. Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the `Sender:` header is only used if someone sends a message on behalf of someone else. For example, a secretary might send an email on behalf of the boss.

If what you want is the `Lastname, Firstname (Companyname)` part of the address, you can do this:

```
foreach (var mailbox in message.Envelope.From.Mailboxes)
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}", mailbox.Name);
```

if what you want is the `f.lastname@company.com` part of the email address, then what you want to do is:

```
foreach (var mailbox in message.Envelope.From.Mailboxes)
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}", mailbox.Address);
```